# A non parametric equivalent to MANOVA

Tags: nonparametric, manova

I would like to investigate whether there are significant differences between three different groups. There are about 20 numerical attributes for these groups. For each attribute there are about a thousand observations.

My first thought was to calculate a manova. Unfortunately, the data are not normally distributed (tested with Anderson Darling test). From just looking at the data, the distribution is too narrow around the mean and has no tail at all.
When I calculate the Manova anyway, highly significant results come out that are completely against my expectations.

My question is whether anyone knows a non parametric euqivalent to the MANOVA that does not require normally distributed data.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot! :)